# Error when classifying new Linear SVM dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I created a multi-class classification model with Linear SVM. But I am not able to classify a new loaded dataframe (my base that must be classified) I have the following error.

**What should I do to convert my new text(df.reason_text) to TFID and classify(call model.prediction(?)) with my model?**

Training Model

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), stop_words=stopwords) 
features = tfidf.fit_transform(training.Description).toarray()
labels = training.category_id

model = LinearSVC()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, indices_train, indices_test = train_test_split(features, labels, training.index, test_size=0.33, random_state=0)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Now I'm not able to convert my new dataframe to classify

Load New DataFrame by Classification

```
from pyathena import connect
import pandas as pd
conn = connect(s3_staging_dir='s3://athenaxxxxxxxx/result/', 
                   region_name='us-east-2')
df = pd.read_sql("select * from data.classification_text_reason", conn)

features2 = tfidf.fit_transform(df.reason_text).toarray()
features2.shape
```

After I convert the new data frame text with TFID and have it sorted, I get the following message

```
y_pred1 = model.predict(features2)
```

error

```
ValueError: X has 1272 features per sample; expecting 5319
```

'

Comment: `features2 = tfidf.fit_transform(df.reason_text).toarray()` change it to `features2 = tfidf.transform(df.reason_text).toarray()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are loading a new DF for classification, you are calling fit_tranform() again, but you should be calling only transform().

fit_transform() [description](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform): `Learn vocabulary and idf, return term-document matrix.`

transform() [description](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.transform): `Transform documents to document-term matrix.`

You need to use the transformer created when training the algorithm, so the code would be:

```
tfidf.transform(df.reason_text).toarray()
```

If you still have the feature shape error, there may be a problem with the shapes of the arrays. Solve the transform part and if the error still occurs, post an example of the train and the test data in array format, I will keep helping.